# Modificar el valor de un campo de un modelo dependiendo de la fecha - Django

Tags: django

tengo un modelo tal que este:

```
class EdicionPrograma(models.Model):
   nombre_programa = models.ForeignKey(Programa)
   edicion = models.CharField(
       verbose_name="Edicion",
       blank=False,
       max_length=100
   )
   curso = models.CharField(
       max_length=255,
       verbose_name="Curso",
       blank=False
   )
   fecha_inicio = models.DateField(
       verbose_name="Fecha de inicio",
       blank=False
   )
   fecha_fin = models.DateField(
       verbose_name="Fecha de fin",
       blank=False
   )
   edicion_para_empresa=models.BooleanField(
       default=False,
       verbose_name="¿Empresa?",
       blank=False
   )
   abierta = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   class Meta:
       verbose_name = u"Edición"
       verbose_name_plural = u"Ediciones"
       ordering = ['nombre_programa']

   def __str__(self):
       return "{}".format(self.edicion)`
```

Y necesito que el campo **abierta** modifique su valor a True o False dependiendo si la fecha del día actual es `>` que fecha_fin.

Alguien sabría como hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres cambiar el valor a todos los registros, lo más fácil es hacer una migración de datos, en la cual, tendrás que especificar que quieres hacer, Así creas la migración:

```
~$ python manage.py makemigrations --empty app_name
```

Para saber más de como configurar la migración, mira [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

Y en la función para migrar hacer algo así:

```
...
def migrar_booleanfield_abierta(apps, schema_editor):
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    EdicionPrograma = apps.get_model('app_name', 'EdicionPrograma')

    EdicionPrograma.objects.update(
        abierta=models.Case(
            models.When(fecha_fin__lt=timezone.now(), then=True)
        ), default=False
    )
...
```

Lo bueno de hacer eso es que quedan sus datos guardados en la base de datos, lo malo, es que solo se hace una vez, por lo que lo segundo que recomiendo es hacer un método en el modelo que le indique si está **abierta** o no, de la siguiente forma:

En models.py (luego del método **str**):

```
@property
def abierta(self):
   from django.utils import timezone
   return self.fecha_fin < timezone.now()
```

Con este método, trabajaría igual que con el campo actual, lo único, es que tendría que borrar el campo actual de `abierta` para usar este, y no podría hacer querysets.

Alguna duda o si algo no funciona, déjala en los comentarios.

Comment: Muy claramente explicado, muchas gracias ahora lo probaré. Pero, esto se comprobará diariamente?

Comment: No, la migración solo se hace una vez, y el método solo será cuando cuando lo llames, pero recuerda que no necesitarás tener el valor en la base de datos, por lo que te ahorrarías tener que hacerlo diariamente, si no solo cuando se necesite, si quisieras hacerlo diariamente ya necesitarías un manejador de tareas como Celery o algo por el estilo que te permita ejecutar tareas cada cierto tiempo