# ¿Como insertar datos en un campo dependiendo de otro campo?

Tags: django, registro

Necesito ayuda amigos! soy nuevo en django.
tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
class Bala(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    bala = models.ForeignKey(TipoBala, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    porciento = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    litros = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2) 
    entrada = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

En el formulario inserto los datos de cada uno de los campos, menos el campo de `porciento` el cual es el resultado de `litros` dividido entre 100.
Lo que ocurre es que no se como hacerlo, si se debe hacer en el `CreateView` o en el `Form`. Les pido que me ayuden con esto.

despues de insertar un registro me deverian quedar de la siguiente forma: `fecha`: 2023-01-10, `bala`: Bala1, `porciento`: 19.5, `litros`: 1950, `entrada`: 200.

Pero logicamente el `porciento` siempre me da vacio ya no se de que forma seguir intentandolo!

Comment: Lo intento con la ayuda de este post: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51439/modificar-el-valor-de-un-campo-de-un-modelo-dependiendo-de-la-fecha-django?rq=1]

En el modelo, despues del __str__ pongo la siguiente función:
`def porciento(self):
        return self.litros / 100`


Automaticamente todos los campos de `porciento` se guardan con porciento, sin embargo no me sirve ya que no puedo utilizar _queryset_ lo cual es fundamental para continuar trabajando con estos datos.

Si alguien puede aportar otra solucion lo agradeceria bastante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo tengo implementada esta solución en el modelo y lo actualiza automáticamente y es visible el campo cuando haces un Queryset.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self.porciento = self.litros / 100

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: muchas gracias! ahora si funciona perfectamente!